# What difference does it make between a single integral and a double integral in surfaces?

Tags: surface-integrals, divergence-operator

I am a little confused what difference is there when it comes to first and double integrals when dealing with surfaces.  For example if have to find 
$$\int_S (2xy\textbf{i} + yz^2\textbf{j} +xz\textbf{k}) \,dS$$

were the region is bounded by x = 0, y = 0, y = 3, z=0 and x + 2z = 6.

So if the divergence theorem is utilized, by simply finding the div(F) and the volume of the whole region, this integral could be worked out.

So why exactly, the divergence theorem is always stated as:

$$\iint_S \textbf{F}.\textbf{N}dS = \iiint_V  div(\textbf{F})dV  $$

Where here was have a double integral instead of a single integral of the whole surface?

Comment: It may be a question of notation. Mathematicians usually tend to write $\int$ for both $\iint$ and $\iiint$.

Comment: And on the right-hand side one normally writes $dV$ as the volume element to emphasize the fact that one integrates over a volume.

Comment: @NDewolf Yes you are right, my mistake when typing in the equation.  Fixed it now.

Comment: There one can say that  ??$$\iint_S \textbf{F}.\textbf{N}dS = \int_S \textbf{F}.\textbf{N}dS   $$   is this correct ?@Kusma

Comment: I write the divergence theorem as something like $\int_V \operatorname{div} F \, dV=\int_S (F\cdot n) \, dS$. Some of your textbooks may use $\iint$ and $\iiint$ to stress that the integrals are surface and volume integrals. Others may not. There is no completely uniform notation in mathematics.